# How to Access Variable from Another Class without Creating New Object

Tags: java, class, variables

My overly long title says it all... I want to be able to access a variable from another class without creating a new object.

Currently the only way I know how to access another class's variable is:

```
Control control = new Control;

int dirtCount = control.dirtCount;
```

However, if I want to access this variable in my dirt object, I would have to create a new Control object for each one. This creates an endless cycle...

how can I access the variable without creating a new object?

(If you want to see the rest of my code, I can post it. I think that this part is the most relevant though :))

Comment: Read up on class variables and instance variables.

Comment: have you heard of static variables?  Although I think that @SotiriosDelimanolis advice is good.

Comment: What about staic variable / class variable. Read [Understanding Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One way would be declaring that variable as `static`, which means that it's a **class variable** (it's different than an *instance variable*). From [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) (emphasis mine):

> They are associated with the class, rather than with any object. Every instance of the class shares a class variable, which is in one fixed location in memory. Any object can change the value of a class variable, but **class variables can also be manipulated without creating an instance of the class**.

In the `Control` class:

```
public class Control {
    public static int dirCount;
    // ...
}
```

and you can use it without creating an instance:

```
int dirCount = Control.dirCount;
```

**Note:**

If you want that variable to be `private` you can define a `static` getter method:

```
public static int getDirCount() {
    return dirCount;
}
```

and you can call that method with

```
int dirCount = Control.getDirCount();
```

Comment: Thank you! I've used the static keyword before, but I had gotten "static" and "final" confused! I still have one issue: I made the variable static, and made a getter the same as yours, but when I tried to call it from my other class, I got this error message: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getDirtCount() from the type Control". What should I do to correct this? Thank you again!

Comment: Since the method `getDirCount` will be `static`, you **cannot** use any `non-static` field or method inside. Make sure you only use `static` fields inside a `static` method. If you have `dirCount` and ` getDirCount()` identical to what I posted, there shouldn't be problem. Please check that you have the `static` keyword when declaring `dirCount` and `getDirCount`.

Comment: That isn't the problem... I can make the method `getDirCount` just fine, but the problem is that I cannot set a variable in the `Dirt` class to `getDirCount` in anything but the constructor for that class. I put this in the constructor

Comment: Ugh sorry I pressed enter. Anyway, I put this in the constructor: `int dirtNumber2 = Control.getDirtCount();
  this.dirtNumber = dirtNumber2;`, and that worked, but I need to update the variable every step. I have a method that updates every step, but I get the error that I mentioned last time when I put what I have in the constructor in there. I have tried making the class static, but that didn't work because I don't want the variable in the `Dirt` class to be static. I guess what I need to do is convert the static variable into a non-static variable? Thank you again!

Comment: If it make sense (for your program) you can do everything `static`. But it depends on what is your class intended to do. An instance of `Dirt` won't never be created?

Comment: Is there another place I can message you? I think it would be helpful to show you what scripts I have, and be able to write out a better formatted message... But the short of it is that I can the instances of Dirt just fine, but they only are able to read the `static` variable `dirtCount` in their constructor, nowhere else. Thank you for your continued help!

Comment: Yes, we can talk in a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/13767/christian)

Comment: Ok, the strangest thing happened this morning. I kind of removed most things that I had in place, typed them back in, and it works now! I must have had something wrong the first time. Thank you for your help!

Comment: This worked great, I'm such a doof, been struggling with a way to share variables across multiple classes without a new instance and didn't even think of this.

Answer (score 2):

In java a class can have two type of member variables

1) instance variables - they are created with every object of that class, and can be access   by object of that class.

2) class variables - they are belongs to class means each and every object can share same variable and can be access by class name

[image: Member variables in java]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must read a little bit static variables. You can check it at http://www.caveofprogramming.com/frontpage/articles/java/java-for-beginners-static-variables-what-are-they/