# How to access members of a parent class without an object?

Tags: java

Say we have the classes `A`, `B` and `C` like so:

```
class A {
     int a; //let variable a
}

class B extends A{
     int b; //let variable b
}

class C extends B{
     int c; //let variable c
}
```

How can I access `a` from class `A` in class `C` without an object of class 'A'?

Comment: These are _instance variables_, so by definition, you need an object instance to access them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Access Variable from Another Class without Creating New Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22626695/how-to-access-variable-from-another-class-without-creating-new-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always make the variable static.
For example:

```
class A {
     static int a;
}
class B extends A{
     int b;
}

class C extends B{
     int c;
}
```

Then you could do System.out.println(C.a)

Answer (score 1):

By definition you need an instance so this works just fine

```
C cVar = new C();
System.out.printf("%d %d\n", cVar.a, cVar.b);
```

Class `C` inherits the instance variables `a` and `b` as long as they are not declared `private` in the superclass.  If they are `private` then the superclass would have to provide a getter method if it wanted to expose the *values*.

Comment: The question asks without an object, so I would mention that **you need an object**, because it's an *instance* variable.

Comment: Essentially this works because `cVar` is an instance of `A` (and `C`).

Comment: Originally that's not what it asked,.

Comment: @DavidChoweller See the edit history. All I did was make it clearer.

Comment: actually whenever we want to access 'a' in class C we must need an object of class B or class A;
but how can it be possible to access without object reference

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use it in class C. You don't need object of class A. 
If you want to access it outside the C class and variable is not static, it's simply not possible.